# Area of a 3D surface

Tags: calculus, surfaces

I need to compute the area of a $3D$ sphere centered on $0;0;0$ and the book I'm following says:

"If a curve $y = f (x)$ from $y = a$ to $y = b$ is revolved around the $x$ axis, the surface area of the resulting swept surface is"

[image]

What is this formula? I've never seen it before. I'd like to get a simple explanation on this or at least a simple proof why this should work

Comment: Wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution is very detailed

Comment: [This](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/ESSENTIAL%20CALCULUS%20Early%20Transcendentals/upfiles/topics/ess_at_06_asr_stu.pdf) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's proved on [the wikipedia page for surface of revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution) (not solid of revolution). That page also covers the specific case of a sphere.